# Генерация документа .doc (docx) в браузере

Tags: asp.net

Подскажите с реализацией: задача стоит в том, чтобы редактировать документ .doc (.docx) с веб страницы. Поясню, пользователь заходит на страничку и видит перед собой поля для ввода (как MS Office), редактирует на свой лад, документ генерируется и юзер получает ссылку на скачивание. В общем, как в Google Docs).
Необходимый браузер MS IE.
Скажите, на .ASP возможно реализовать подобное?

Comment: Microsoft Office Web Apps? Реализовать всё возможно, зависит от навыков и желания)

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать с помощью Open XML SDK - он позволяет редактировать документы из пакетов Office 2007 и выше. Это можно реализовать с помощью ASP.NET (насчет чистого ASP не в курсе)  Что касается документов .doc, то тут ничего сказать не могу - я работал только с  документами Office 2007-2010, но Open XML тут точно не поможет. Здесь, насколько знаю, надо работать с COM-библиотеками.